# How do you map a texture to a sphere in Unity using script?

Tags: c#, unity

I am looking to map a texture to a sphere inside of Unity using c# (not in the visual editor)?

dragging a jpg or other image resource onto the sphere is the effect I am looking for -- but I would like to do it at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually pretty simple. All you need to do is change the Material property of the sphere's renderer.

Simply place the Texture you'd like to use at runtime within your Resources folder. Then you can do the following:

```
Texture2d runtimeTexture = (Texture2d) Resources.Load("Textures/YourTexture");
Material runtimeMaterial = new Material(Shader.Find("VertexLit"));
runtimeMaterial.maintexture = runtimeTexture;
//assuming sphere is a GameObject or Monobehavior
sphere.renderer.material = runtimeMaterial;
```

Answer (score 1):

Raven's answer, while correct, doesn't really explain the underlying concept you need to understand. Textures aren't technically applied to meshes directly; instead, Textures are assigned to Materials, and then Materials are assigned to Meshes. Thus you either need to change the texture assigned to the material that's assigned to the mesh, or (as in his code) assign a different material to the mesh.

(incidentally, dragging an image onto a mesh in Unity is actually a shortcut to generating a new material. Notice how a new material is created when you do that? What's happening is Unity creates a material, assigns the texture to that material, and then assigns that material to the mesh. You could also create a Material yourself and do it all explicitly.)